# How to Set Url for Update Data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

My Friend
my problem with URL $category in Laravel update post
my view update post:

```
{{--insert category--}}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {{Form::model($category,['method'=>'patch','url'=>['category/update',$category->id]])}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form::text('category','',['class'=>'form-control text-right','placeholder'=>'submit'])}}
            </div>
            {{form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
```

my route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('update/{id}', 'categoryController@update');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::post('update/{id}', 'categoryController@patchUpdate');
});
```

my controller:

```
public function update($id){
    Category::find($id);
    return view('admin.updateCategory',compact('id'));
}

public function patchUpdate($id,request $request){
    $category = Category::find($id);
    return redirect('category');
}
```

my error is:

```
Undefined variable: category (View: C:\wamp\www\pc\resources\views\admin\updateCategory.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error fixed by change `form::open` :

```
            {{Form::open()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form::text('category','',['class'=>'form-control text-right','placeholder'=>'submit'])}}
            </div>
            {{form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `$id` to the view instead of the category

```
public function update($id){
  $category = Category::find($id);
  return view('admin.updateCategory',compact('category'));
}
```

Comment: tnx but submit  is error :NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: